# Adding the search button and filter button to a single button in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, web, django-models, django-forms

Here I am trying to activate two functions with one button.
How would it be to write the search button and filter system in a single function, as shown in the examples? I used the django filters framework for the filter.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrZhl.png)

This is my `views.py` file

```
def job_list(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    locations = Location.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    jobtypes = JobType.objects.all()
    experiences = Experience.objects.all()
    qualifications = Qualification.objects.all()
    genders = Gender.objects.all()

    #filter start
    my_filter = JobFilter(request.GET, queryset=jobs)
    jobs = my_filter.qs
    #filter done



    context = {
        'jobs': jobs,
        'categories': categories,
        'locations': locations,
        'jobtypes': jobtypes,
        'experiences': experiences,
        'qualifications': qualifications,
        'genders': genders,
        'my_filter': my_filter,
    }

    return render(request, 'jobs.html', context)
```

Here is my `filters.py` file

```
import django_filters

from . models import Job

class JobFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['location', 'category', 'experience', 'qualification', 'jobtype', 'gender']
```

this is the search function
I also defined a URL to the search function in url.py.

```
def search(request):

    search_query = ''
    if request.GET.get('search'):
        search_query = request.GET.get('search')

        """aynı şeyleri göstermez... distinct"""

    jobs = Job.objects.distinct().filter(
        Q(name__icontains = search_query) | Q(description__icontains = search_query) | Q(category__name__icontains = search_query)
        )
        
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        'jobs': jobs,
        'categories': categories,
        'search_query': search_query,

    }
    return render(request, 'jobs.html', context)
```

I tried many functions but there was no solution.